# Cannot reset my developer account Password as i don't have the number linked to it nowl

Tags: login

My name is akhil and i have a developer account with username: chikkaraju.akhil1@nagarro.com and the email that is linked with that account is : chikkaraju.akhil@nagarro.com.

The problem that i'm facing right now is when i'm trying to reset the password for my account it is sending a verification code on to my mobile number which doesn't exist anymore. can anyone please help me in resetting my password??

Note : I'm the only administrator in this account. So the answer of contacting my administrator doesn't work i guess.

Akhil

Comment: Hi Akhil, You can mention askSalesforce on twitter, they reply and help you reset your password. https://twitter.com/asksalesforce

Answer (score 2):

[Submit a case](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/help?article=Lost-access-to-my-Salesforce-User-and-Trailhead&topic=Trailhead_Account&topicName=Trailhead%20Account&groupName=Trailhead_Support)  with support and provide as much detail as you can (i.e. full name on the account, email address related to the account, profile ID or URL, etc.)

**Prevent this from happening again:** Connect a personal Trailhead Playground login, Developer Edition login, or Social Login to ensure that you always have a personal identity to use to access your Trailhead progress and history.

Answer (score 0):

As the user said you need to submit a case. Note that Dev Orgs couldn't submit cases last time I checked so might need to go through another org and give full details of what you're trying to recover.

You should generally activate 2FA with a ver code that you generate on a TOTP app to avoid these sort of things.